# Constant 'XXX' used before being initialized

Tags: swift

I am new in swift .. anyone help me to understand why this error throwing

> Constant 'parsedResult' used before being initialized

on the other hand if i set `return` in the `catch`  then compile error gone .what is the relation each other. explain please .

Here is my code :

```
 if let data = data {
     let parsedResult : AnyObject!
          do {
              parsedResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
                                            }
           catch{
                print("something  worng ")
                // return

             }
             // error compiler error this line 
                    print(parsedResult)
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily fixed by declaring parseResult as AnyObject? which means it will be initialised to nil. The print will print an optional value which it can do just fine.

Be careful with the words you use. "// error throwing this line " is totally misleading. There is no error thrown at this line. Errors are thrown at runtime. You have the compiler reporting an error at this line. Be precise.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your code currently, `parsedResult` might be uninitialized when you reach the `print(parsedResult)` statement.

This can be the case when the `try` statement **throws an error**. `parsedResult` would still be uninitialized, the program would continue with the `catch` block, print "something wrong" and then just continue (trying to print `parsedResult`).

If you, however, insert a `return` in your `catch` block it ensures that in the case of an error, you wouldn't continue to the `print(parsedResult)` line.